# VBA. Parsing data from site

Tags: html, vba, parsing

I'm trying to parse data (e.g. product status - "Available online") from [walmart](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/fitbit-versa-2-smartwatch-petalcopper-rose-aluminum/6000200312589?rrid=richrelevance)

But when i try to use:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/fitbit-versa-2-smartwatch-petalcopper-rose-aluminum/6000200312589?rrid=richrelevance", False
    .send
    ftext = .responseText
End With
```

I can’t even find this phrase in the Response Text.

So how to act in this case, when you can not directly access the page code?

Comment: Where on page do you see "Available now" ? I see "Available online".

Comment: Of cause online. typo. sorry.